# $Ax=b$ doesn't have a solution, $Ax=0$ has infinite number of solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

$A$ is a real matrix of size $m \times n$. If $Ax=b$ has no solution then $Ax=0$ has an infinite number of solutions. I've been told this claim is **not** true but can't find an opposite example.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I'm ok thanks to everyone, how do i set the question as solved? just to write in the header that it's solved? thank you :)

Comment: you have to accept, take a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Ax=b$ has not solutions it simply means that **b is not in the column space** of $A$. But $A $ can be full rank column thus $Ax=0 \iff x=0$.

**EG**

$A=[e_1 e_2]$ and $b=e_3$

**NOTE**

What is true is that if $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions then $Ax=b$ has no solution or infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: look for examples with $m=2, n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $Ax=B$ has no solutions then the rank of $A$ is less than rank of the augmented matrix $[A|B]$. This means $A$ should have number of independent equations less than the number of variables, which should lead us to the conclusion that $A$ will have infinite number of solutions. But consider $A$ as a $2$ x $1$ matrix like $$2x = 7$$
and $$3x = 14$$
Here $A$ is [2 3]' and $B$ is [7 14]'. $[A|B]$ has rank 2 but $A$ will have rank 1. Thus $$Ax = B$$ will have no solution. But $$Ax = 0$$ will have one solution (not infinite). This should answer you.